# How do I get a local file with the HTML5 File API's getfile()?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, fileapi

I'm working on a Cordova app for Windows 8 and trying to use the HTML5 File API to get a file and copy it to another destination.

I have a local file in my `www` folder in a folder called `db`. My javascript file is located in the `www/js` folder.

I'm using this code to create an instance of `requestFileSystem()`:

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 2 * 1024 * 1024, initFS, errorHandler);

function initFS(fs) {
    console.log('woot!');
}
function errorHandler(err) {
    console.log(err.code);
}
```

inside my `initFS` function I need to get my file, test if it exists at a destination, if it doesn't then copy the file. I want to create a `copyFile` function and pass it "from" directory, the file, and the destination

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 2 * 1024 * 1024, initFS, errorHandler);

    function initFS(fs) {
        var fromLocation = [local db directory];
        var myFile = [file stored in the local db directory];
        var toLocation = [destination to copy to];
        copyFile(fromLocation, myFile, toLocation);
    }

    function errorHandler(err) {
        console.log(err.code);
    }

    function copyFile(fromLoc, src, toLoc){
        //copy the file to the new location
    }
```

All the examples I've read talk about how to create and manipulate a file but none talk about manipulating a file that already exists.

Comment: Just note that this API is [obsolete](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/) now (Chrome being the only one supporting it, for now).

Comment: I'm using [Cordova Plugin File](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) that is still being contributed to so hopefully that won't be an issue. However, do you have a suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: This file system is sandboxed from the system, and the OS file system is also sandboxed so there is no way to load a file directly from the system automatically. The only way to do this is to let the user pick the file from the system using File API and a FileReader object, then save it back by again letting user select destination via a Data-URI or Object-URL. It's due to security.

Comment: Read it as ArrayBuffer (if binary) or just text. Then do the changes, create a blob of it and an object url. Set the url on f.ex. an A-tag or window.location (won't work in IE), and let the user click the link/select destination (blob can take mime-types). (hopefully I didn't misunderstand your question - it's getting late here.. :) )

Comment: I have a pre-populated database (myDB.db) in my apps `db` folder. I need to copy that to AppData folder so the app can access it. I can get the AppData folder by using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path`. I'm using a cordova plugin that creates that file using that location but I need to copy not create.

Comment: All this happens using the `ondeviceready` listener.

Comment: I may have a workaround. All I need to do is see if a file exists outside of app at the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path` location I can use my SQLite plugin to create the DB then parse and run a sql file...

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm fixing this is running a SQLite statement using the [Cordova SQLite Storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin that checks if the table exists. If it doesn't then a table is created and an set of inserts are run. If the table does exist nothing happens.

The open db statement will always create a db if one doesn't exist. If the db exists it isn't overwritten.